# Diacritics in Wordpress working but not showing the specific font one`s

Tags: php, css, wordpress, fonts, diacritics

So I have a problem with diacritics in wordpress.This is the website http://colectia-harnau.ro This is the div for first category:

```
<div style="font-family: 'Sancreek', cursive;font-size:110%;">
<a href="http://colectia-harnau.ro/?page_id=1949">SUPORTURI PREZENTARE</a>
</div>
```

As you can see on google fonts, this font have diacritics like ă,ș,ț etc. Here is the font URL: https://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Sancreek
As you can see here the diacritics are loaded but showed with different font
[image]

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Have you made sure you are using the extended latin character sets? Like this: `<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Sancreek&subset=latin,latin-ext' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>`. Note the **latin-ext**

Comment: yes this was the problem thank you very much sir ! I wish I coud send you a beer !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you are using the extended latin character sets. Like this:

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Sancreek&subset=latin,latin-ext' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>.
```

Note the **latin-ext**

Answer (score 0):

Ok , problem solved!
For those who will occur this issue. You need to select the Larin extended option from 2nd selector!

Latin Extended (latin-ext)