# Certain diacritic replaces the font on render in wordpress

Tags: php, css, wordpress, fonts, diacritics

I am working on a wordpress website, on which I installed SlupyTheme from Themeforest. I added a custom font, Verlag, which is branded to my company to display on the whole website.

The problem is that "ț" is not rendered with my Verlag font, but with Sans-Serif. The website is UTF8, I registered the font as subset latin-ext and put the mappings with Font-Creator as intended (021B). The other romanian diacritics (ș, ă, â, î) work fine, as well as their capital companions.

Can you please give me some suggestions? Thank you a lot!

Website: [www.leaders.ro/v2](http://www.leaders.ro/v2), look at the section "Recomandări parteneri" (scroll to the middle of the homepage, right side)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Diacritics in Wordpress working but not showing the specific font one\`s](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22973771/diacritics-in-wordpress-working-but-not-showing-the-specific-font-ones)

Comment: It is not the same thing. There, he couldn't use any diacritics. My problem is that only "ț" does not work... And I did try all the solutions given there, still does not work..

Comment: I see. Well, maybe the problem is a smaller subset of that one, and is a starting point for future searchers. It's just a link, it's not an accusation :)

Comment: No accusation presumed :) Just that I tried everything known and read on the Internet so far... a bit frustrating.

Comment: Ok, taking a look at the page source... I see that there are some issues in your Verlag font link: I see some &amp; in the querystring instead of normal &. Is that correct?

Comment: On the other hand, I don't find any "Verlag" font in googlefonts...

Comment: It is not a google font. It is a custom font I uploaded on the server. The theme let's me add the custom font, but for a reason I don't actually know, it searches it on googlefonts. No biggie as far as I can see, because it works, except for that certain symbol...

Comment: When I open your website, I see everything in Sans-serif. So I do think that's the core of the problem.

Comment: Now that you mentioned it, I checked it on another desktop and loads only Sans Serif indeed. I will address this problem, but I think it is a problem with the font itself after doing some more research. Thank you!

Comment: Practical question: are you seeing this for the single glyph `ț` (U+021B) or the compound string `ț`, which consists of two glyphs: the letter `t`, followed by the combining comma below diacritic (U+0326)?

Comment: I see this for U+021B. The font works just fine in Word or all other programs. It has something to do with the way it works in browsers I think. The other diacritics work just fine.